# Running MySql command from terminal not working

Tags: mysql, linux, terminal

So I want to pipe my netstat output into a mysql database

The plan is to make it a continuous crontab event. That way I can store that data and use it elsewhere easily.

I figured before I could figure that part out though I needed to figure out how to run a SQL Command from terminal.

It seems pretty straight forward

```
sudo mysql -u username -pMYPassword -e "SQL COMMAND"
```

This however doesn't work...

When I run this it prints the MYSQL Help

When I run this though

```
sudo mysql -u username -p -e "SQL COMMAND"
```

everything works perfect, it just prompts me for a password

Now I don't know if it makes a difference or not but my DB password does have exclamation points in it. It is also over 15 chars long

Could either of these be an issue?

Comment: Are you trying to execute first(not-working) command in shell or via crontab? Also I don't see where you're specifying DB to operate on (if that's necessary for your SQL, of course)

Comment: I tried doing it from terminal and the command I was running was SHOW DATABASES

Comment: Your syntax (with `SHOW DATABASES`) is correct (and works well). So I have two guesses. First - your password contains special symbpols and need to be escaped in order to be used inside `crontab`. Second - you're not saving your output, thus, not able to realize if all goes well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql -u user -p -e 'SQL Query' database
```

Where,

```
-u : Specify mysql database user name
-p : Prompt for password
-e : Execute sql query
database : Specify database name
```

So the option -p is a **PROMPT**, the password need not to be linked, but to be separated from it:

```
sudo mysql -u username -p'PassWord' -e 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table'
```

**EDIT**: If your real password contains special characters, you need to escape them.

Comment: So this answer did work however there is no space between the -p flag and the password.

Comment: By "separated" I meant the password to not to be joined with the option -p, the quotes are the mark of such separation, although both options will work, with or without space after -p, but quotes ARE mandatory.

Comment: I tried it with a space and it prompted me for a password as if I hadn't typed it in at all

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try : `sudo mysql -u username -p'MYPassword' -e "SQL COMMAND"`

Or : `sudo mysql -u username --password=MyPassword -e "SQL COMMAND"`